# What identifies Web Part? Solution, GUID, Alias, Name?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts

In the deployment process, what distinguishes new web parts from new versions of existing ones?

I assumed it to be web part GUID only, but based on testing it appears that its parent solution matters too, and that its complete identity involves solution name and GUID plus web part GUID, alias, and maybe name.

Want to know what identifiers to pay attention to when "forking" an existing project or "merging" a new one.

Answer (score -1):

AppCatalog is essentially a SharePoint site, Apps for SharePoint is essentially a SharePoint libarry to store apps.When we change a ordinary item,it's Id and Guid will not change，it will only modify the version number if we enable version management.
So in the library, both id and guid can uniquely identify app.